# GET parameter Unexpectedly surrounded by %27?

Tags: php

I cannot see the issue, i am not encoding the parameter, i am just passing the variable from page to page.

Here is Page A:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])==1){ ?>
  <td><a href="processors/process.php?i='<?php echo $editID; ?>'">Edit</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

This is how i am retrieving the parameter on Page B:

```
$editID = $_GET['i'];
```

Expected output:

```
i=15
```

Current Output:

```
i=%2715%27
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? Because when i manually change the parameter to 15 it displays how it should.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`%27` is the hex code for single quote `'`. It's happening because you put quotes around `<?php echo $editID; ?>`:

```
<td><a href="processors/process.php?i='<?php echo $editID; ?>'">Edit</a></td>
                                here--^             and here-^
```

It should be:

```
<td><a href="processors/process.php?i=<?php echo $editID; ?>">Edit</a></td>
```

Comment: Thanks mate, i never knew about that quote thing.

Comment: You knew not to put them there when you put a literal `15` into the parameter, didn't you?

Comment: @Elevant if he answered your question you should mark his answer as resolved

Comment: Yeah i know i had to wait a new minutes XD

Answer (score 0):

%27 is an apostrophe. you put your `<?php echo $editId; ?>` between quotes and those get carried into the GET header I think. try this.

```
if (isset($_SESSION['loggedIn'])==1){ ?>
  <td><a href="processors/process.php?i=<?php echo $editID ?>">Edit</a></td>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: You need to use `echo` if you're going to do variable substitution like that.

Comment: oh, my bad. I thought it was inside php code, sorry!